# History.js doesn't load js scripts properly

Tags: javascript, history.js

I recently completed my CMS and I am running a website on it but here's the problem; scripts like Instagram and reCAPTCHA run on the first load but I'm using History.js and whenever I click through links and go back and forwarth I can't get the scripts like Instagram and reCAPTCHA to load.

I don't know if it's the numbers being added to the end or something else but I want to know why this behavior is happening. I want my instagram images to load and I want to be able to load my instagram images as well.

Here's an image for guidance.

[embed.js with numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABut5.jpg)